# C# Get SpeechRecognitionEngine to recognize sentences

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, grammar, speech

If I give Microsoft's `SpeechRecognitionEngine` a `Grammar`, it will only recognize individual choices in that grammar instead of combinations of choices.

Is there any built in way to get it to recognize combinations of choices instead of a single choice at a time without, adding that combination to the choices.

----For example, have it recognize `"Open Firefox"`, instead of `"Open"` and then `"FIrefox"`

Code below

```
namespace SpeachTest
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        MainClass main = new MainClass(); 
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

            Choices choiceList = new Choices();

            choiceList.Add(new string[]{"Hello", "Open", "Close", "Firefox"} );
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(choiceList);

            sre.SpeechRecognized += main.sreEvent;
            sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sre.LoadGrammar(grammar);

            sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            while(true){
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        void sreEvent(Object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e){
            Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
    }
}

}
```

I know `DictationGrammar` would do this but I would like to avoid using due to the fact that is has low accuracy.

Comment: Try looking at [GrammarBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554240(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You are overlooking the obvious solution, simply add "Open Firefox" to the Choices.  Works just fine when I try it, in spite of my Dutch lilt..

Comment: @tyh - I've looked at the grammar bulider class, but found nothing of use.

Comment: @Hans Passant - If I did it the way you've suggested, I would have to add every single possible combination for every choice

Comment: Check [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362944%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to see how to use GrammarBuilder to construct sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder();
Choices choice = new Choices (new string[] {"Open", "Close"});
builder.Append(choice);
builder.Append("Firefox");
Grammar grammar = new Grammar(builder);
```

Creates a `Grammar` which handles both "Open Firefox" and "Close Firefox."

Now if you are thinking

> Well that means I need to create tons of boiler plate code to create
>   all my Grammars since I want to be able to recognize hundreds of
>   phrases like "Open Notepad," "Close Chrome," and "Minimize Visual Studio."

You could create some sort of factory which returns `Grammar` that have certain default choices like Open, Close, Minimize, Maximize, Focus, etc...

Comment: While not exactly that I was hoping for. This dose work, and solve my problem